# Ldap java, significance of 'dc' in active directory group's objectcategory attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Firstly, I am sorry for a bit confusing title of question.
My question is rather simple.

I have an active directory group with following configuration:

> Base DN: DC=nam,DC=nsroot,DC=net
>
> dn:CN=SAN_Support,OU=Legacy_Grps,OU=ICGCORP,DC=nam,DC=nsroot,DC=net
>
> cn: SAN_Support
>
> member: CN=user,OU=Users,OU=CTI_REG,OU=CTI_DFW,OU=SYS,DC=nam,DC=nsroot,DC=net
>
> distinguishedName: CN=SAN_Support,OU=Legacy_Grps,OU=ICGCORP,DC=nam,DC=nsroot,DC=net
>
> objectCategory: CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=nsroot,DC=net

Here I am using a user **user@nam.nsroot.net** to log into AD in java ldap.
And when I run the query **objectcategory=group**, I don't get this group in result.
**I have no idea why this is happening and my guess is-

The DC values in object category attribute are different than other attributes, as *DC=nam* is missing.**

Can someone help me out with the issue here ?

Comment: Are you supplying the base dn during the search? Can you try changing it to dc=nsroot,dc=net?

Comment: for ObjectCategory Look at: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677612(v=vs.85).aspx